# OWLClass representation in JSON format

Tags: owl, owl-api

I know it is possible to save the whole ontology in JSON, would it be possible to convert single OWLClass to JSON?
Something like:

```
OWLClass cl = ...;
JSONObject obj = cl.toJSON();
Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no ready method to do that in OWLAPI, however an `OWLClass` consists of just an `IRI`, whose only data is a string. So it is pretty simple to serialize a single object as a string plus a type specification, and deserialize accordingly.

An introduction to custom serialization for JSON is available [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)